# Customize URL for each user in Angular 2

Tags: angular, url, url-rewriting, customization

I want to see an user's username as part of URL. For example:

I have an URL like this:

```
 www.undefiend.com/panel/dashboard
```

I want to customize it for every user. Like this:

```
www.undefiend.com/user1/dashboard
```

- or

  www.undefiend.com/michael/mails
- or

  www.undefiend.com/richard/profile

an others...

How can I do that in Angular 2 or above ?

Any helps would be great. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the router with a param in the route

```
routes = [
  { path: ':user', children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, }
  ]},
  { path: '**', component: 'LoginComponent' }
];
```

And in the login component you then navigate to the route with the user

```
this.router.navigate(['/' + username, 'dashboard']);
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard

Comment: It's sense. Start the link with a parameter. Then set children. Thanks @Günter Zöchbauer. I think you're the most helpful about angular in the stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks, glad to hear you find it helpful :)